getting error : Object variable or with block variable not set
I don't what is wrong with this code. finding the error during the compile time
Dim Start As Long, Finish As Long, Accounts As New Collection
Dim Account As String, Movement As String, i As Long, j As Long, Col As Range
Set Col = Wsh.Columns(AccountColumn).Range

'Find row where input data starts
Start = Col.Find(What:="???????", _
    After:=Wsh.Cells(MovementRow, AccountColumn), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Finish = Wsh.Cells(Wsh.Rows.Count, AccountColumn).End(xlUp).Row


There are some missing pieces in your code. It won't pass VBE compilation.

You need to assign the value/object the varibles before using it.
Line Set Col = ... raises runtime error 91 without Set Wsh = Sheets("Sheet1").
If the target value isn't found in the Col1, Find returns nothing, resulting in an error when trying to access Find().Row.

Pls try.

Dim Start As Long, Finish As Long, Accounts As New Collection
'Dim Account As String, Movement As String, i As Long, j As Long
Dim Wsh as Worksheet, Col As Range
Set Wsh = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
Dim AccountColumn As Long, MovementRow As Long
MovementRow = 1  ' modify as needed
AccountColumn = 2   ' modify as needed
Set Col = Wsh.Columns(AccountColumn)
Dim c As Range
Set c = Col.Find(What:="???????", _
    After:=Wsh.Cells(MovementRow, AccountColumn), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Start = c.Row
    Finish = Wsh.Cells(Wsh.Rows.Count, AccountColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    ' your code
Else
    MsgBox "Cant find ??"
    Exit Sub
End If

